# getting results wih different endianess

Tags: c++, qt

depending on how I print out an integer value in hexadecimal form, I get results with different endianess

the following code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

template<class T>
QByteArray numToHex( T number )  // converts any number to hex format
{
     return QByteArray( (const char*)&number, sizeof(T) ).toHex();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    quint64 hash64 = 18144624926692707313;
    qDebug() << "<< hex << hash64: " << hex << hash64;
    qDebug() << "numToHex(hash64):" << numToHex(hash64);

    return a.exec();
}

//this is the result: 
<< hex << hash64:  fbcea83c8a378bf1
numToHex(hash64):  "f18b378a3ca8cefb"
```

Both results have different endianess, why?
I didn't set endianess in any case, so they should be the same!

Comment: Because you're running this on a little-endian machine, so when you grab the raw bytes, and format them individually, the little endian comes out first. But when you ask your C++ library to format an `int64`, it obviously knows that the big endian is *over there*, and the big endian, as expected, always comes out first.

Comment: thanks, I was not aware of that

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in one case you're going to an external library and giving it the address of (one particular byte of) a 64-bit integer and asking it to construct a particular class from the data at that address. Then you're asking that class to output its contents as "hex" (actually, as a string). Whether or not the two techniques produce the same result will depend on whether that first byte (the address of which you pass to `numToHex`) is actually the most significant byte of the `qint64` or the least... in other words, your results depend on your platform's endian-ness.